# How to detect from raw packet if it contains a HTTP Get or Post?

Tags: .net, networking, pcap

I have just started to do some network programming. I am using the pcap [pcap.NET](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)to get hold of network packets. My question is, can I extract from the "payload" part of the packet a HTTP Get or Post request? Does this mean I need to read individual bytes from the payload to detect if I have the specific protocol?

Any guides are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http methods are not part of the packets - as in the first XX bytes of the packet header = method.

You will need to read the stream and do a string check. The method is usually the first part of the message so you only need a small bit of data.

Comment: How come? I was using wireshark and at the raw byte level could see "Get", so i thought I might need to check the bytes.

Comment: yes you need to check the bytes in the payload. My comment was you won't be able to determine what the method is from the packet header for example. you will need to read from the data.

Comment: OK, so this means the payload is to be examined, so I was on the right track?

Comment: yep. How you actually read the payload using your libraries, I don't know.

Comment: I basically get a complete packet = headers + payload. I know the header. But was not sure if I were to use the payload in terms of raw bytes or convert the bytes to strings and then investigate the strings. Nevertheless, you have given me some hint. Thanks